# adding hyperlinks in some cells openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, hyperlink, openpyxl

I have to generate an excel with summary results. The results are included in a list. Some of the elements are values and some links.

I managed to generate the excel with the right format but not generate the hyperlink in some of the cells

My try:
from openpyxl import Workbook

```
from openpyxl.styles import PatternFill, Border, Side, Alignment, Protection, Font, Fill
from openpyxl.cell import get_column_letter

def summaryMCP(self,result):

            c1=Column('Name',[result[0]])
            c2=Column('R2 check',[result[1]])
            c3=Column('Dir Diff.',[result[2]])

            c4=Column('CHI2 Sm-Sc',[result[3]])#Lets say this one is a hyperlink to one image png
            c5=Column('Rose Sm-Sc',[result[4]])

            s=Sheet("MCP main results", [c1,c2,c3,c4,c5]
            excelMCP([s],"/results.xlsx") 

def excelMCP(self, sheets,foname):
            wb = Workbook()
            ws = wb.active
            #from here format options (a bit long)
```

My question is can I define that the value is a hyperlink when defining the Column in def summaryMCP and then in excelMCP the format of the link?? And in case, how ? I could not find it so far

Comment: What's a `Column`? I don't understand this code.

Comment: Column is a header. It is the first row in the excel sheet. result is the values (one row). result[number] is each cell in the row

Comment: Yes, but it's not an openpyxl object so you're asking about an unknown.

Answer (score 26):

This works for me:

```
wbook.active['A8'].hyperlink = "http://www.espn.com"
wbook.active['A8'].value = 'ESPN'
wbook.active['A8'].style = "Hyperlink"
```

Answer (score 21):

If wanting to use Excel's built in hyperlink function directly, you can use the following to format as a link:

`'=HYPERLINK("{}", "{}")'.format(link, "Link Name")`

e.g. `ws.cell(row=1, column=1).value = '=HYPERLINK("{}", "{}")'.format(link, "Link Name")`

Comment: It's useful, but when i click on the cell or edit it's not a hyperlink any more I became text with data `=HYPERLINK("https://google.com", "Google")`

Comment: Be careful with this approach...  excel can't handle formula > 256 chars so long urls may get truncated using HYPERLINK()

Answer (score 10):

Try this :

```
sheet['A1'].hyperlink = "http://stackoverflow.com"
sheet['A1'].value="StackOverflow"
```

In my try this does not add the formatting that Excel puts with a hyperlink but the cell contents are more like the Excel hyperlink cell than I get with the HYPERLINK tag.

Comment: If you want the formatting you need to add the correct named style.

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me.

```
sheet.column_dimensions["A"].width = 30
sheet.cell(row=1, column=1).hyperlink = "http://www.espn.com"
book.save('links.xlsx')
```

Comment: This way the value and the URL will be the same, but that's what I wanted.