Add mailto in one cell in openpyxl
I need to add a cell that call the default mail program to send a mail,
in html is using the mailto tag but didn't find a way of doing that in a Excel file generated from openpyxl.
The code to insert a url is in this post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39077661/adding-hyperlinks-in-some-cells-openpyxl
`
wbook.active['A8'].hyperlink = "http://www.saftparaexcel.com"
wbook.active['A8'].value = 'SAF-t para Excel'
wbook.active['A8'].style = "Hyperlink"

`

And what is your question? If you want mailto then change the hyperlink to 'mailto', e.g wbook.active['A8'].hyperlink = "mailto:moken@gmail.com?Subject=Hello?cc=meme@gmail.com"

@moken that's it! thanks a lot.
